# Build failed. - erro ao criar migração

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core, migrations, dotnet-cli

Boa tarde.

Estou iniciando um projeto web que está gerando erro ao usar o comando: "dotnet ef database drop" Usei no final do comando -v para gerar mensagem completa.

**Mensagem de erro:**

```
Build failed.

1 Error(s)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.CommandException: Build failed.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Project.Build()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.RootCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

já configurei a `ConnectionString`;
inseri todos os `PackageReference` do `entity` no `csproj`
criei o modelo e contexto
configurei a classe program.cs
configurei a classe startup

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0):

Certifique-se que o seu projeto compila corretamente antes de executar os comandos `dotnet ef`.

É possível verificar os erros pela sua IDE (como visual studio) out editor (como VS Code), out mesmo pela linha de comando, com `dotnet build`.

Depois de corrigir todos os erros de compilação deverá ser possível correr os comandos do entity framework.

Comment: não estava compilando nenhum mas antes estava.

verifiquei os erros pelo IDE e e reinstalei novamente

após isso os erros foram corrigidos e criei nova pasta do projeto e deu certo.